# Struts 1 + Spring 3 Language and Theme Support + Tiles

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, tiles, struts-1

I am working on an old Struts 1 application. I have tried to add Theme and Internationalization (i18n) / Localization (L10n) support from Spring 3 MVC.

This is the code:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Struts Configuration -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>validate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>autowire</param-name>
        <param-value>byName</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- Struts Configuration -->

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->

<!-- welcome file list -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.do?method=test</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!-- welcome file list -->

<!-- tld configuration -->
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
<!-- tld configuration -->
```

struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
"/WEB-INF/tiles-config.dtd"><struts-config>
<form-beans>
<form-bean name="myForm" type="forms.myForm" />
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
<action name="myForm" type="actions.myFormAction"
        path="/welcome" scope="request" parameter="method">
        <forward name="signin" path="welcome" />
    </action></action-mappings>

<controller>
    <set-property property="processorClass"
        value="actions.CustomRequestProcessor" />
</controller>

<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin">
    <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
    <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
</plug-in>

<plug-in className="org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn">
    <set-property property="contextConfigLocation"
        value="/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml" />
</plug-in>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <!--  <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" /> -->
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/classes/resources/Applicationresource" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="5"/>
    <property name="UseCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
</bean>

<!-- Locale Change Intercepter and Resolver definition -->
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>


<bean id="themeSource"
    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
</bean>

<!-- Theme Change Intercepter and Resolver definition -->
<bean id="themeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="themeAndLanguageInterceptor"
        class="common.interceptor.ThemeAndLanguageInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="LUSSI" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="handlerInterceptorclass" class="common.interceptor.HandlerInterceptor">
        <property name="themParamName" value="theme" />
        <property name="languagParamName" value="language" />
    </bean>

</mvc:interceptors>
```

tiles-defs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 1.1//EN" "/WEB-INF/tiles-config.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition1" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout1.jsp">
<put name="body" value="" />
</definition>
<definition name="welcome" extends="base.definition1">
<put name="title" value="Home" />
<put name="body" value="/home.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

home.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<spring:theme code='css'/>" />
```

But when I run the application, I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Theme 'theme': No message found under code 'css' for locale 'en_IN'.
```

Does someone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That isn't going to work first the interceptors aren't doing anything as those are only useful inside a `DispatcherServlet` and spring based handlers. Next your resolvers aren't of much use because they aren't exposed, next to the `ContextLoaderListener register a `RequestContextListener` which might give you some I18N support but only for the default settings locale. Final note you are loading the same configuration twice, once by the struts plugin and once inside the `ContextLoaderListener` basically duplicating all of your beans.

Comment: can you please advise me as to what needs to be done about this???

Comment: It will not work fully inside a struts only environment, unless you do some integration between struts and spring for changing the locale. Which means basically porting the functionality of the `ThemeChangeInterceptor` and `LocaleChangeInterceptor` to a Struts equivalent. Another solution would be to add a `DispatcherServlet` and put the `ActionServlet` behind the `DispatcherServlet` using a `ServletForwardingController` or `ServletWrappingController`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletForwardingController.html

Comment: thanks for the advice but i'm really confused...

Comment: i have fixed the error... but now the interceptors aren't working..... please help me....